# Elasticsearch Complex Filter Logic

Tags: elasticsearch

If someone could post and example of how to do this, it would answer nearly every question I've had about how filtering works in Elasticsearch.

Assume A, B, C, D, E, etc are fields, and a1, a2, …, b1, b2, ...etc are possible values for those fields. Also assume that any of these fields could have multiple values.

How would I perform filtering with the logic below:

A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1) AND ((D=d1) OR (D=d2)) AND (((E=e1) OR (E=e2)) AND (F=f1)) OR (((G=g1) AND (G=g2)) AND (H=h1))

This is not an actual query I'm trying to write, however it has all the pieces of queries that I'd like to write.

I know how to do A=a1 and (B=b1 or B=b2). For example, below I search for the terms "something to search" in documents where CustomerID=113 AND (TypeID=91 OR TypeID=70).

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "something to search"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "CustomerID": "113"
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "TypeID": [
                    91,
                    70
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling, however, to figure out how to combine the rest of these filters.

A full example would be awesome!

Comment: Are you sure you want a filter? This complex filter will be reused many times? You could try to generate a query_string like the one you showed and submit along the search, something like: `(something to search) AND (A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1) AND ((D=d1) OR (D=d2)) AND (((E=e1) OR (E=e2)) AND (F=f1)) OR (((G=g1) AND (G=g2)) AND (H=h1)))`

Comment: A filter would be preferable. Some of these searches will be used over and over, yes, while others would be less often used. I'm mainly trying to grasp how filters can be combined in different ways, and haven't seen any examples that make it clear how the overall structure works. I've seen examples of AND filters, OR filters, and BOOL filters/queries, but none of those examples have been complex enough to show how these things can play together.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is basically what you showed in the snippet. You would use [AND filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/) and [OR filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html) in a nested way. For example, considering: `A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1)`. You would have:

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "something to search"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": { "A": "a1" }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": { "B": "b1 }
              },
              {
                "term": { "C": "c1 }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assume that you're constructing these JSONs programmatically, so it isn't hard to, given a complex logic, construct an equivalent filter in the JSON.

If the problem is how to convert a input **textual query** like `"A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1)"` to a corresponding representation in memory of the logic, then you'd be better off just using a [query filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html) with a `query_string` query. You'll probably do not want to manually parse the logic.

Answer (score 1):

The OR filter contains 2 or more subqueries where one must match. The And filter contains 2 or more subqueries where all must match. Combine and nest them, and you get a lot of 
posibilities.

To acomplish what you ask for: A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1) AND ((D=d1) OR (D=d2)) AND (((E=e1) OR (E=e2)) AND (F=f1)) OR (((G=g1) AND (G=g2)) AND (H=h1))

```
{
   "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "something to search"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "term": {
              "A": "a1"
            }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "B": "b1"
                }
              }, {
                "term": {
                  "C": "c1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "terms": 
              {
                "D": [ "d1", "d2" ]
              }
          },
          {
            "terms": 
              {
                "E": [ "e1", "e2" ]
              }
          },
          {
            "or": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "F": "f1"
                }
              }, {
                "term": {
                  "G": "g1"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "term": 
              {
                "G": "g2"
              }
          },
          {
            "term": 
              {
                "H": "h1"
              }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not shure i've counted the paranteces correct, but hopefully you see the picture.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm still a little confused, so bear with me.

In your example, it appears to me (could be wrong) that the logic for A=a1 AND (B=b1 OR C=c1)  is the same as the logic being used for  OR (((G=g1) AND (G=g2)) AND (H=h1))

Or, put another way, it looks to me like your logic for OR (((G=g1) AND (G=g2)) AND (H=h1)) would actually work out to: OR (F=f1 or g=g1) AND (G=g2) AND (H=h1). 

Essentially, it seems like the G=g2 and H=1 subfilters are on top level, when I really want them a level deeper. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, I may actually see what's going on here now. Going to test some things and will post back. Thanks,